# How to add unknown amount of identities to a list with a max amount

Tags: java, arrays

Edit:

This is a really rough draft, but I have yet to figure out how to ask the user how to get out of these loops because if I set the MAX_ON_LIST back to 50. It'll prompt me 50 times, I only want it to prompt as long as the user wants to prompt

Also, I don't think I've solved how to only add names and credits to the array only if credits is greater than or equal to 30 and less than 90

```
 final int MAX_ON_LIST = 3;

  String[] stuName = new String[MAX_ON_LIST];
  int[] numCredits = new int[MAX_ON_LIST];

  for (int i = 0; i < stuName.length; i++) {
     do {
        try {
           stuName[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter student name:");

        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           stuName[i] = "";
        }
        if (stuName[i].equals("")) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name cannot be blank");
        }
     } while (stuName[i].equals(""));
  }

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(stuName));

  for (int i = 0; i < numCredits.length; i++) {

     do {
        try {
           numCredits[i] = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter # of completed credits:"));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
           numCredits[i] = -1;
        }
        if (numCredits[i] < 0) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "# of credits can't be less than 0");
        }
     } while (numCredits[i] < 0);
  }

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Arrays.toString(numCredits));
```

I'm having some trouble solving this problem with the rules below:

I have to create a list of up to 50 eligible students.

Student names and their corresponding number of credits is tracked.

Only if number of credits is within a range are they considered eligible and then name and credits will be added to the list.

How would I go about solving this without using ArrayList?

All I know is the list cannot exceed 50 people, but the user can stop adding people to the list before it gets to 50.

Comment: Start coding, show us some code and ask more specific question. There are many grad schemes. You could use a backing array as datastructure or some kind of linked nodes, but really there are many possibilities.

Comment: Mind that your `array` of students does not have to be full, all you need is a way of tracking how many of the 50 indexes are currently in use(hint: you need an `int` value for that).

Comment: @DimaMaligin A count?

Comment: @dan You should really try to write some code(it may help). To get started create a `Student[] students = new Student[50]` and an `int numStudents = 0` and increment it after a student is added, to loop the `array` go from `0` to `numStudents -  1` in other words `for(int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++){ students[i].setCredits(80) or what ever  }`

Comment: @DimaMaligin I added some code

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
public void addStudent(Student s) {
   if (valid(s) && yourList.size() < 50) {
      yourList.add(s);
   }
}

public boolean valid(Student s) {
   // check your credits
}
```